# Callback won't be called in recursive function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, callback

I can't understand why a callback won't be called in the following function. Strangely everything other then the callback in the `else` block gets called. Putting the callback anywhere in the `if` statement also works.

I can't figure out why it would skip the callback.

```
var get_page = function(options, callback){

request_wrapper(c_url(options), function(xml){

    parseString(xml, function (err, result) {

        if(result["feed"]["entry"] != undefined){

            async.eachSeries(result["feed"]["entry"], function(entry, iter) {

                total_entries++;
                iter();

            },function(){
                options.start = total_entries;
                get_page(options, function(){
                });
            });

            // callback({}); works anywhere in the if statement.

        }else{ 

            callback({}); // Doesn't work here.

            // But this shows.
            console.log("TOTAL ENTRIES HERE: "+total_entries);   

            //So why is callback in the same block not being called?

        }
    });
}); 
}
```

Here's the function I'm calling from, if that helps. As I said, it does output, just not in the else block.

```
exports.scrape = function(options, callback){
    get_page(options, function(ob){
        console.log(ob);
    });
}
```

UPDATE:
I just accidentally stumbled upon the answer. The recursive call should not have been like this:

```
get_page(options, function(){
});
```

It should have included the callback in the function parameter, like this:

```
get_page(options, callback);
```

This is a solution to my problem, but I'm not sure I understand why it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is `typeof callback` a `function`?

Comment: How exactly do you know it's not being called? You didn't post what the callback function itself looks like, nor did you post the way that `get_page()` itself is initially called.

Comment: Is it because your test case never gone through the `else` block?

Comment: @Pointy : I've updated the code to include the call.

Comment: @Chris'o: I'm sure its going through the else block because the console gets outputted.

Comment: @dboskovic: I'm not sure what you mean. Its a callback function that works in the if statement but not in the else statement.

Comment: @AppTest callback is not populated the first time you initiate `get_page({...})` is it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to put the callback execution after you if/else ?

```
var get_page = function(options, callback){

request_wrapper(c_url(options), function(xml){

    parseString(xml, function (err, result) {

        if(result["feed"]["entry"] != undefined){

            async.eachSeries(result["feed"]["entry"], function(entry, iter) {

                total_entries++;
                iter();

            },function(){
                options.start = total_entries;
                get_page(options, function(){
                });
            });

        }else{ 
            // But this shows.
            console.log("TOTAL ENTRIES HERE: "+total_entries);   
        }

        callback({}); // Does this work ?

    });
});
```

}

Comment: You can also add the "debugger" keyword in your code and make step by step to check why your method is not executed.

Comment: Thanks, but it has to be in the else statement because that's when the process completes.

Comment: which "process" / method ?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant I could only call the callback when the purpose of the function was complete. In this case the function scrapes a website.